# Доступ к лейблам,созданным программно

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте,в классе задаю массив лейблов `Queue<int>[] QArray;`, затем по нажатию первой кнопки вызывается следующий код инициализирующий массив и задающий лейблы

```
labelArray = new Label[M];
labelArray[i] = new Label();
labelArray[i].Location = new Point(30 + 40 * i, 100);
labelArray[i].Text = QArray[i].Count.ToString();
labelArray[i].Size = new Size(25, 15);
this.Controls.Add(labelArray[i]);
```

При нажатии другой кнопки текст лейбла из массив должен измениться:

```
int add = rnd.Next(0, M);
QArray[add].Enqueue(MaximumofM);
labelArray[add].Text =QArray[add].Count.ToString();
```

Но генерируется исключение "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта." Подскажите,что делать,пожалуйста.
Весь код:

```
int MaximumofM = 0;
    int M = 0;
    Queue<int>[] QArray;
    public Label[] labelArray;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        label1.Text = MaximumofM.ToString();
        int add = rnd.Next(0, M);
        QArray[add].Enqueue(MaximumofM);
        labelArray[add].Text =QArray[add].Count.ToString();
        MaximumofM++;
    }

    public void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        M = int.Parse(textBox1.Text); //Количество очередей
        QArray = new Queue<int>[M];
        int [] Array = new int[30];
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            Array[i] = i + 1; 
        }
        int ArrayCount = 30;
        int MaximumValue;
        int element;
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {

            {
                MaximumValue = 0;
                QArray[i] = new Queue<int>();
                int count = rnd.Next(1, 8); //Количество элементов в очереди
                for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
                {
                    if (ArrayCount > 0)
                    {
                        if (MaximumValue == 30) break;
                        element = rnd.Next(0, 30);
                        do
                        {
                            element = rnd.Next(0, 30);
                            if (Array[element] < MaximumValue) continue;
                        } while (Array[element] == 0);
                        MaximumValue = Array[element];
                        Array[element] = 0;
                        QArray[i].Enqueue(Array[element]);
                        ArrayCount--;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (MaximumValue > MaximumofM) MaximumofM = MaximumValue;
            labelArray = new Label[M];
            labelArray[i] = new Label();
            labelArray[i].Location = new Point(30 + 40 * i, 100);
            labelArray[i].Text = QArray[i].Count.ToString();
            labelArray[i].Size = new Size(25, 15);
            this.Controls.Add(labelArray[i]);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Будьте так добры, покажите весь код.

Comment: @post_zeew добавил

Comment: Что-то у Вас со скобками какая-то путаница. Насколько я понимаю, Вы на каждой итерации цикла создаете новый массив `labelArray`. Попробуйте создать этот массив перед циклом: уберите строку `labelArray = new Label[M]` оттуда, где она есть сейчас, и поместите ее перед циклом `for`.

Comment: @post_zeew Вроде как, помогло,спасибо большое )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы на каждой итерации цикла создаете новый объект `labelArray`, в итоге, у Вас инициализируется только его последний элемент.

Решается эта проблема путем выделения памяти под массив перед циклом, т.е. вынесением строчки `labelArray = new Label[M];` из цикла в место перед ним:

```
labelArray = new Label[M];
for(...)
{
    ....
}
```